# Using awk gensub if other columns meet certain conditions

Tags: awk, command-line

I want to replace every time "end" shows up in column 4 with "p11" if column 5 contains "p", and replace it with "q11" if column 5 contains "q"

I want to replace every time "end" shows up in column 5 with "p11" if column 4 contains "p", and replace it with "q11" if column 4 contains "q"

With  this input

```
Bill    89  22  9end    q12 2683    2687
Sue     21  20  4end p13 9390    9302
Sam     89  9   p12 p11 9029    9032
Lee     39  20  q12 6end 3892    9032
Smitty  93  7   p13 5end 3902    3902
```

I want

```
Bill    89  22  q11 q12 2683    2687
Sue     21  20  p11 p13 9390    9302
Sam     89  9   p12 p11 9029    9032
Lee     39  20  q12 q11 3892    9032
Smitty  93  7   p13 p11 3902    3902
```

As output

.

..

I basically want a command like this but with correct syntax and that prints the non-matching lines unadjusted

```
awk BEGIN {OFS="\t"} ($5 ~ /q/ {$4=gensub(/[0-9]end/,"q11",1,$4); print}) || ($5 ~ /p/ {$4=gensub(/[0-9]end/,"p11",1,$4); print}) || ($4 ~ /q/ {$5=gensub(/[0-9]end/,"q11",1,$4); print}) || ($4 ~ /q/ {$5=gensub(/[0-9]end/,"q11",1,$4); print})' input
```

.

..

I know with this input

```
Steve   89      22      2end    q12     2683    2687
```

I can run this

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} {$4=gensub(/[0-9]end/,"q11",1,$4); print}' input
```

And get this as output

```
Steve   89781   22  q11 q12 26839389    26879820
```

But I want the result to have p11 in column four in column have had p12 instead and I would also like the same awk command to be able to do the same thing with column 5

Please let me know if there's any confusion

Comment: @EdMorton You can just ignore my questions then. I don't know how to use or with gensub, none of my other questions are going to help with that but I am looking through that textbook for it

Comment: @EdMorton The problem is that I want every single line to print but only want certain lines matching a condition have a substitution performed on them. If I run something like 'awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} $5 ~ /q/ {$4=gensub(/[0-9]end/,"q11",1,$4); print} input' then only one line will print. I want something that prints every single line and substitues different based on the columns

Comment: so step 1 is to move the `print` outside of the block that only gets executed when the condition is true, i.e. change `/foo/{bar; print}` to `/foo/{bar} {print}`. Look, I know it's hard to take the time to read a tutorial or book first when you just want to get a job done (believe me - I'm learning Ruby On Rails right now with a 5-day course before attempting my first task using it) but if you don't do that you just waste a ton of your own time wondering how to do the simplest of things and have to clean up a ton of mistakes later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple way to do what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
($4 ~ /end/) && match($5,/[pq]/,a) { $4 = a[0] "11" }
($5 ~ /end/) && match($4,/[pq]/,a) { $5 = a[0] "11" }
{ $1=$1; print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Bill    89      22      q11     q12     2683    2687
Sue     21      20      p11     p13     9390    9302
Sam     89      9       p12     p11     9029    9032
Lee     39      20      q12     q11     3892    9032
Smitty  93      7       p13     p11     3902    3902
```

The above uses GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match(), with other awks use match()/substr().

Read the book...